# what ACTION use to detect a reader nfc the same as SCL011?

Tags: android-intent, nfc, intentfilter

I tried with the three actions to discover NFC READER SCL011 .
The system can't verify this condition:

```
if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)).
```

I use this  tech list :

```
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
```

I don't know what exactly tech can I use for this reader . 
is there another action without ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED , ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED, ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED ??

Answer (score 0):

The NFC technology classes in Android refer to (passive) tags, not (active) readers. You cannot communicate with a reader in Android. The only exception is when the reader can also do NFC peer-to-peer communication (ISO 18092), in which case you need the SNEP protocol to send or receive an NDEF message to/from Android.